# Android plugin and toolkit configuration, after user change

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I used to use eclipse as root and since its bad practice I decided to change user. I started eclipse as user instead but had problems since I installed all the plugins as root.

I uninstalled them as root.

Then I installed them as user but now I cannot see any trace of them except that they show up in installed software in eclipse.

Im running Ubuntu, Linux

What can I do to make the ADT plugin work as normal user now when the configuration is f*cked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice is to not have a shared installation of eclipse using the package manager, but instead (as standard user) to download Eclipse from eclipse.org and to unzip it into a location of your choice at a place where your standard user *can write*. That way you avoid the problems with restricted access, and you also can always upgrade easily to service releases, which are often not available in package manager versions of Eclipse.

Afterwards in your new Eclipse installation use File->Import->Install->From existing installation and point it to your old Eclipse installation to easily re-install all plugins which you used up to now.

Comment: Okey, sound like a good idea but I would prefare to patch my current installation since I cant figure out why the plugins don't show up.

Comment: I totally don't understand why you prefer to have a potentially days consuming investigation of the current situation, which may not even lead to having a working environment, and will make more people at this site think about a dozen potential problems, when there is a 10 minute way of surely fixing the issue.